# Call function N times and store result in an array using lamba

Tags: c#, lambda

I would like to call a function N times and store result in an array (or append the result to a list) in lambda-y way.  How would I do that?

I've tried `Enumerable.Repeat( fun(), n ).ToArray();` which would be ideal, except that fun() is only called once.

Comment: You need to add more details. What type of objects - details man!

Comment: With a reference to the array or the list in the lambda, probably a captured variable.

Comment: @DonA - Lets say there is a function with no parameters, returning an int.  It seems like I should be able to use Enumerator.Repeat, but I'm pretty tired right now.

Comment: "I'm pretty tired right now": and you are already in your pyjamas ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call a random function n-times and keep all the results.

```
IEnumerable<T> CallRepeatedly<T>(Func<T> a, int count)
{
    for(int i=0; i<count; i++)
    { 
       yield return a();
    }
    yield break;
}
```

Is something like that what you were looking for?  I am not sure the conditions under which Func would return a different result on each call, but you can easily refactor to take the index as an argument.

Comment: I wasn't thinking of anything like that, wild!

Comment: +1 for essentially explanation how BrokenGlass' solution works. I would use `Enumerable.Range` version as it have the same behavior, but give less chance of errors. Side note: there is no need for `yield break` at the end of function - it is implied.

Comment: If you add it to a little class like `public static class Enumerable {...}` it's like the method you wanted wasn't missing.

Answer (score 2):

Let's suppose your function takes an integer parameter, then something like this would work (otherwise substitute with the parameters that you need):

```
int n = 10;
var results = Enumerable.Range(0, n)
                        .Select(myFunction)
                        .ToArray();
```

In the example `myFunction` would be any `Func<int, T>` where `T` is your return type.